# Shop is broken after Cookie Plugin

Tags: shopware

i disabled and activated the shopware cookie manager and after that i get this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Less_Exception_Compiler: Recursive variable definition for
> @text-color-dark in advanced-menu.less on line 3, column 22 1| // Advanced menu container that contains every category listing 2| 3| @adv-menu-header-bg: @text-color-dark; 4| @adv-menu-header-text-color: @btn-secondary-text-color; 5| @adv-menu-bg: @btn-secondary-text-color; 6| @adv-menu-text-color: @text-color-dark;
>
> in /var/www/virtual/MYSHOP.de/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Variable.php:35 Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/virtual/MYSHOP.de/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Expression.php(51): Less_Tree_Variable->compile(Object(Less_Environment)) #1 /var/www/virtual/MYSHOP.de/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Value.php(26): Less_Tree_Expression->compile(Object(Less_Environment)) #2 /var/www/virtual/MYSHOP.de/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Rule.php(73): Less_Tree_Value->compile(Object(Less_Environment)) #3
> /var/www/virtual/MYSHOP.de/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Ruleset. in /var/www/virtual/MYSHOP.de/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Variable.php on line 35

i don't know what i can do, switching theme does not work and nobody change anything on theme.

Comment: Which plugin are you talking about? Is it a paid plugin? If so, you might want to concat the support.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:
Shopware's plugin "SwagCookieConsentManager" was activated during the update. This could no longer be activated on 5.6. If you delete it afterwards, there are inexplicable problems. Solution: Uninstall the plugin but do not delete it. It must remain on the FTP.